# What happens if the implementation of IHostedService.StopAsync method does not respond to cancellation requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-hosted-services

We are implementing a .NET core 3.1 worker service and we need to register several hosted service to implement the required business.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) explains that the [StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.stopasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostedService_StopAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method of the [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) interface should be able to listen to cancellation requests issued after a default 5 seconds timeout.

Based on my understanding, the [StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.stopasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostedService_StopAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method is called by the host during the shutdown process of the host itself.

In one of our hosted services we need to call an async method during the hosted service stop process; unfortunately this method does **not** support cancellation, so there is not a simple way for us to implement the [StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.stopasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostedService_StopAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method in the proper way.

This is our scenario:

```
public sealed class MyHostedService : IHostedService 
{
     public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token)
     {
          _logger.LogInformation("Stopping the service....");

           await DoSomethingAsync(); // this method does not support cancellation, so I can't pass the cancellation token here

          _logger.LogInformation("Service was stopped");
     }
}
```

What's going to happen at the host level in this scenario ?

Is this implementation "dangerous" in any sort ?

Is this going to block the host shutdown process in case of a long time needed to complete the execution of `StopAsync` ?

The simplest solution to this issue is implementing the class `MyHostedService`  by deriving from the [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)  base class, but I would like to fully understand the possible implications of a long running `StopAsync` implementation at the host level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosted Services are stopped in the reverse order from which they were started (which is also the order you add them to the `ServiceCollection`). You can extend the shutdown timeout by specifying `HostOptions.ShutdownTimeout` which otherwise defaults to five seconds:

```
services.Configure<HostOptions>(s => s.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

When the `Host` is stopping its hosted services it does so in a loop, running over the services in reverse order. Once `StopAsync` is called for a particular service, [the host will wait for `StopAsync` to return](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a014fbddebf153d11e908dc7ff36dae6fb1ece48/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L83). So if that one service doesn't respect cancellation, the host will take a while to shutdown.

The host also calls `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in that loop prior to calling `StopAsync` on each service. What this means is that if the timeout elapses while the *first* service is stopping, it will finish completing* but before the *next* service's `StopAsync` is called an exception will be thrown. This will cause the shutdown process to **abort**, and for the process to exit ungracefully.

This abort can also happen after all services have been stopped if the timeout elapses in the very next instant (there is another `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` immediately after the loop). Anything bound to the Host/Application lifetimes will be skipped.

Moral of the story is to either ensure your services can stop quickly, don't require your services to *need* graceful termination, or *increase the timeout*. You can also make sure you add the services to the collection in such a way that the more important or quicker  ones get stopped first (by adding them last) and your long running service gets stopped last (by adding it *first*).

* Assuming the service doesn't respect cancellation

Answer (score 0):

Based on [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#shutdown-timeout) and [web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#shutdown-timeout) hosts shutdown timeout docs the host will just stop corresponding services ungracefully:

> If the timeout period expires before all of the hosted services stop, any remaining active services are stopped when the app shuts down. The services stop even if they haven't finished processing. If services require additional time to stop, increase the timeout.

So long running `StopAsync` should not prevent the host from proceeding with shutdown. The only bad thing that can happen is that your `DoSomethingAsync` will be interrupted in some invalid state, if that is possible.